# My batch script is not working, I have no idea why

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've spent my recent hours researching batch scripting and compiling my own program using lua, and batch. One of my batch files isn't working properly and I have 0 idea why. I have edited the script a bit since then but not anything that would change how it works.

This batch script is making you enter a password when you start it up. When I answer with the correct password it will say ACCESS GRANTED. And when entering it wrong it should say ACCESS DENIED. But what is happening instead is that when I enter the wrong password, it says ACCESS GRANTED. I cannot seem to find why this doesn't work.

```
@echo off
color A
set password=YOUR PASSWORD HERE

:start
cls
echo Welcome!
echo Please input password:
set /p passwordinput=

if %passwordinput%==%password% (
cls
color 2
echo ACCESS GRANTED!
timeout /t -1
goto access
) else (
cls
color C
echo ACCESS DENIED
echo TRY AGAIN
timeout /t -1
cls
color a
goto start
)

:access
cls
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *always* use quotes in if string compares, else you got syntax errors when one string contains spaces.

```
if "%passwordinput%" == "%password%" (
...
```

Comment: …but, 'The C0mpu1er', as we've no idea which characters are allowed in the password, the above may still not work as intended. _(Passwords including a doublequote character for instance)._

Comment: @Compo True, but explaining delayed expansion at this point, probably overwhelmed the questioner